# How to extend the user registration in Drupal 7

Tags: users

I want to run a set of php code(not drupal code) after the user submits the registration form.

1. user enter details
2. submit the form drupal
3. writes form data to db
4. execute custom code
5. comes back to default registration tanakyou page of drupal

For this how will i extend the default user module of drupal without touching the core user module codes.

can i define a custom module and execute its resources

Comment: Do you want to add `custom field` you can use `Profile Module`. And for executing your custom code you have to add your custom submit function using `hook_form_alter`.

Comment: _run a set of php code(not drupal code)_ - how can one write Drupal code without using PHP? Drupal's core and its API uses PHP (just an FYI) ;-)

Comment: @indrock: php coding that does not follow drupal coding standards

Comment: @SumitMadan: i know how to add fields to registration form admin. but i want to insert some data to an erp systems db(mysql) build in php.

Comment: @zamil - by not following coding standards, you are most likely to make your code vulnerable to attacks (spam bots, sql injection, etc). And there is separate [Security](http://drupal.org/security) team, which works to find such loop holes. So, if you are __sure__ your PHP code is _bug-free_ than, you can ignore the coding standards ;-) Drupal is more secure as compared to other CMSs and a major reason is its CODING STANDARDS :-)

Comment: @indrock:why not, I can write php codes bugs free :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add any action you want after user registered by implementing [hook_user_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7).

Comment: Where will i write this hook_user_insert, do i need to declare a custom module?

Comment: Yup :) If you want to avoid that, you can setup a new Rule and as action, set PhP code. Debugging and other stuff will be harder but you spare the time of building a module, as you wish.

Comment: hmm Rules.Since i found it very difficult to understand i came here to ask this question. Thanks for the answer, I will try with hook_user_insert

Comment: Anyway, don't hesitate to ask if you want the Rules way of doing it.

Comment: I used rules backend to do this successfully, but i want to do it using module.rules.inc file.which i am finding difficult to understand.If you can help me on that i am thankful to your.Thanks for the support

Comment: Sorry this way's a bit tricky... I'd recommand either Rules-normal-way or hook_user_insert :)